# SQL json_extract return null

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-athena

I am attempting to extract from my json object

```
hits = [{“title”: “Facebook”,
         “domain”: “facebook.com”},
        {“title”: “Linkedin”,
         “domain”: “linkedin.com”}]
```

When I use:
`json_extract(hits,'$.title') as title,`
nothing is returned.
However, when I extract by a scalar value, ex.:
`json_extract_scalar(hits,'$[0].title') as title,`
it works and Facebook is returned.
hits contains a lot of values, so I need to use json_extract in order to get all of them, so I can't do each scalar individually. Any suggestions to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

I get INVALID_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT: Invalid JSON path: '$**.title' as an error for $**.title (double stars). When I try unnest I get INVALID_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT: Cannot unnest type: varchar as an error and INVALID_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT: Cannot unnest type: json. I get SYNTAX_ERROR: line 26:19: Column '$.title' cannot be resolved when I try double quotes

Comment: Use `$**.title` https://www.db-fiddle.com/

Comment: https://athena.guide/articles/unnest-arrays-to-rows/

Comment: use the correct double quotes https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=2c45438c788a251158e62848e97f2a90

Comment: I get INVALID_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT: Invalid JSON path: '$**.title' as an error for $**.title.
When I try unnest I get INVALID_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT: Cannot unnest type: varchar as an error and 
INVALID_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT: Cannot unnest type: json.
I get SYNTAX_ERROR: line 26:19: Column '$.title' cannot be resolved when I try double quotes